# Верстка поиска , поиск

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

такая вот проблема. Нужна верстка чтобы слева я мог выбирать поисковую систему а справа вписывать что я хочу найти. НУЖНА ТОЛЬКО ВЕРСТКА. Если есть идеи , помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Стили можете добавить сами, основной концепт вот

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Yandex</option>
    <option>Google</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```